# Can't install Ubuntu on ASUS laptop

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation

I've been trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on my ASUS x556u laptop. When I get to 'Updates and other software' the installer freezes and is basically stuck loading.

The laptop has 8gb of RAM, and intel i5 6200u and an nvidia 940m.

I've tried adding `nouveau.modeset=0` after splash screen however, but this doesn't help.

Comment: I've had ubuntu 16.04 18.04 and 20.04 on this model. Check your installation media